# uninstall app in android installed from apk

Tags: android, apk

may be this is not the correct place but ...

I developed ant apk in unity for android. I copied it in the phone and installed it. How do I uninstall it now?

long taping and dragging to the bin does not work.

it does not appear in the google play store

Comment: Check this: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/remove-unwanted-apps-android-device/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> may be this is not the correct place but ...

You're right. Your question is for https://android.stackexchange.com/.

> I developed ant apk in unity for android. I copied it in the phone and installed it. How do I uninstall it now?

You can do it this way:

```
Settings > Applications > Choose your app > Uninstall
```

or using [adb](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/help/adb.html):

```
adb uninstall your.app.package.name
```

> long taping and dragging to the bin does not work.

Try to reboot your device.

> it does not appear in the google play store

Correct. Have you upload it to [GooglePlay Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/)? Seems, no. So it wouldn't appear in Google Play :)

Answer (score 0):

settings / applications administration (sorry, my phone is in spanish, so I don't know whats the actual wording in english.
From there you can really see all installed applications and uninstall it.